# Bootstrap Conflicting with other CSS

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

In my website i am designing i have a require header file that allows the user to login and logout aswell as being the navbar. This as its own CSS shown in style.css , which is conflicting with the form i have as content on the page styled with bootstrap.

[image: How header should look]

[image: How header looks with bootstrap conflict]

I have tried to isolate the bootstrap by using the `<div class="bootstrap-iso">` tag and also using `!important` on the header css. None which i have got to the work.

style.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}

.wrapper-main {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-header-main {
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header-logo {
  width: 48px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-header-main img {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-header-main ul {
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-header-main ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-header-main ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #111;

}

.header-login {
  height: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.header-login form {
  height: 100%;
}

.header-login form input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  float: left !important;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.header-login form button {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.header-signup {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 0 6px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 8px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #111;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.section-default {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.login-status {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #111;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #111;
}

/* signup.php */

.form-signup {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 200px;
}

.form-signup input {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  float: left !important;;
  font-family: arial;
}

.form-signup button {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.signuperror {
  padding-top: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.signupsuccess {
  padding-top: 14px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

bookappointment.php

```
<?php

  include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

  require "s_header.php";


?>


<html>

  <body>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bookappointment.css">


  <div class="subnav" style="margin-top:30px">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="bookappointment.php">Book</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="viewappointment.php">View</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="BookingForm" style="margin-top:30px">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">




<form action="includes/book.php" method="post" class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-blue w3-margin">
<h2 class="w3-center">Book Appointment</h2>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-user"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-user"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-envelope-o"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-phone"></i></div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
</div>

  <div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-rest">
        <input type="date" name="date" value="" required></input>
      </div>

   <div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
        <div class="w3-rest">
        <input type="time" name="time" value="" required></input>
  </div>


<div class="w3-row w3-section">
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-pencil"></i></div>


    <div class="w3-rest">
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="message" type="text" placeholder="Message">
    </div>
</div>

<p class="w3-center">
<button type ="submit "class="w3-button w3-section w3-blue w3-ripple"> Book </button>
</p>  




</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: i think there is same image

Comment: if you can include the form with custom css it would be easier for others to help